# How to rescue ''dark photos'' of experimental work?

Tags: photo-editing, contrast, brightness, luminance

I have some photos which I took during some experimental work which ended up being so dark that the details can't really be seen (these are of spheres hitting a body of liquid and splashing).

It will be a bit difficult for me to re-do the experiments so was wondering if someone  can explain how I can fix these images to make the details more visible.  I tried fiddling with contrast and brightness but it produces artefacts and does not sufficiently improve the visibility to be able to see what is happening.

[image]  [image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have the RAW files, or only jpegs?

Comment: I think I have the source .avi video files from which these screenshots are taken.

Comment: Just to set expectations: the most likely answer here is "you can't rescue these images, they're just too dark".

Comment: Ah, that's not going to be on-topic here, I'm afraid. Perhaps https://video.stackexchange.com/questions might be able to help. I very much doubt you'll rescue anything from the jpgs as they are.

Comment: vtc as off-topic. It now exists as a dupe on video & is gathering answers [with a similar conclusion, unfortunately:\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use contrast and brightness because these still assume that the picture is about OK, and do most of the work on mid-tones, and you haven't got any of that. A tool like Curves(*) can help:

[image]

You can slightly bend the diagonal to try to improve on this depending on what you are interested in.

This answer can also convince you that there isn't much to salvage.

(*) Demo done with Gimp, other image editing applications have an equivalent tool.